# Remove the bottom level from a path

Tags: bash

I am writing a script where I want to check if a folder relative to the script's working directory is in the shell's path.

For example, if the project structure is:

```
top/
 bin/
 tests/
  test1/
   foo.sh
  test2/
   foo.sh
```

I want to check if `top/bin` is in `PATH` from either `foo.sh`. I know the following will work:

```
cd ../../bin
if echo $PATH|grep `pwd`; then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure"
fi
```

But then I have to keep track of what directory I started in so I can `cd` back there. Can I do something like chopping off the last two directories after `pwd` and then appending `bin` to that? Is there some other intelligent way to handle this?
As a bonus, I'd like to make this script robust against additional directory levels inside `tests`, but that's not strictly necessary if it complicates things.

Comment: you can use substring manipulation and globbing to do that

Comment: A handy technique to avoid ever needing to cd back is to simply run in a subshell.  Eg, just wrap your command in parens: `( cd ../../bin || exit 1; echo $PATH | tr : \\n | grep -q $(pwd)) && echo Success || echo Failure`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Great tip, I didn't know that! Kind of like save-excursion in elisp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Exits with code 0 if the first argument is on the user's path.
is_on_path() {
  CANONICAL_NAME=$(readlink -f "$1")
  while read -r -d: COMPONENT; do
    if [[ "$CANONICAL_NAME" = "$COMPONENT" ]]; then
      return 0
    fi
  done <<< "$PATH"
  return 1
}
```

- `readlink -f` will evaluate path components like `../..` as needed.
- `read -r -d: COMPONENT` will read a colon-separated list of arguments from its input, into the `COMPONENT` variable.
- `<<< "$PATH"` will pass in the system path into `while`'s stdin.

Now you can call that like this:

```
if is_on_path "../../bin"; then
  echo "Success!"
else
  echo "Failure!"
fi
```

**Bonus:** From here it's pretty easy to recursively apply this to all parent directories:

```
find_matching_ancestor() {
  current_dir=$(pwd)
  while [[ "$current_dir" != "/" ]]; do
    if is_on_path "$current_dir/bin"; then
      echo "$current_dir"
      return 0
    fi
    current_dir=$(dirname "$current_dir")
  done
  return 1
}
```

Comment: Your bonus solution with the while loop and `dirname` is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
echo $PATH | xargs -d: -n1 | grep ^$(readlink -f ../../bin)$ | wc -l
```

Comment: Note that `-d` is a [non-POSIX extension](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/0/xargs/) and is absent in BSD `xargs` (as in Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most reliable sulution would be to put a file with executable bit set to that directory and to use "which".

For example, is /bin on my PATH?

```
which ls
/bin/ls
```